# React - Displaying a loading spinner for a minimum duration

Tags: reactjs

I have 2 questions ...

1. During Registration submission process, I need to display a Loading component until the response is received from the server.

The loading component is not rendering:

```
const Register: FC<RouteComponentProps> = () => {

  const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(false)
  const [success, setSuccess] = useState<boolean>(false)
...

const onSubmit = async(values: Values) => {

  setLoading(true)
  try {
    const response = await register({
      variables: { data: { firstName: values.first_name, lastName: values.last_name, email: values.user_email, password: values.password } }
    })
    setLoading(false)
    if (response && response.data && response.data.register) {
      setSuccess(true)
    }
  } catch (error) {

     setLoading(false)
     ...

  }
}

return (
   ...
   { loading && <Loading/> }
)
```

Where am I wrong, kindly let me know.

2. Sometimes you will find that some web requests are relatively fast (< 0.5 second). In this case, the spinner will become a flicker in a web page and users don’t have enough time to understand what is happening. In order to avoid drastic web page DOM change and to reduce users’ confusion, it would be better to display the spinner for a minimum amount of time (eg, 1 second) no matter how much time it takes for loading data. How can I achieve this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dont need to show loading to min 1 second since loading icon is already shown when fetching data and in real life it will be more than 1 sec.

if u want to set min 1 sec anyways

```
  try {
    const response = await register({
      variables: { data: { firstName: values.first_name, lastName: values.last_name, email: values.user_email, password: values.password } }
    })
//change here
 setTimeout(() => setLoading(false), 1000);
```

Comment: The value 1 second is just there for explaining my viewpoint. Well, if it takes longer than 1 second, the spinner should be there for that amount of time.

Comment: I already had this solution in mind but it can be tested only after I get answer to my first question.

Comment: I was going to say this doesn't fulfill the question at all but then I saw the await and understood the solution, what it does is it will show the loader for at least 1 second if response takes less time and for +1 second if response takes more time, let's say the response takes 3 seconds, then the loader will be shown for 3+1 second. Either way, it does fulfill the requirement of showing the loader properly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To show the spinner for at least 1 second **or** the actual request time if longer than 1 second:

```js
const onSubmit = async(values: Values) => {
  setLoading(true)
  try {
    const now = new Date().valueOf()
    const response = await register(...)
    const waitTime = Math.max(0, -(new Date().valueOf() - now) + 1000)
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, waitTime))
  } catch (error) {
     // handle error
  } finally {
     setLoading(false)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use with Promise.all.
define your fetch and define delay with promise, and you should wait when the fetch and minimum delay will finish.
in general its will be like that:

```
function delayPromise(ms: number) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
const requestPromise= fetch(....);
const res = await Promise.all([requestPromise, delayPromise(1000)]);
```

and in your code I think you need change to:

```
const registerPromise = register({
      variables: { data: { firstName: values.first_name, lastName: values.last_name, email: values.user_email, password: values.password } }
    });
const res = await Promise.all([registerPromise, delayPromise(1000)]); // your register response found in res[0]
```